# Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed error when using vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

So I am new to VBA and just starting to learn.  I am practicing using a Vlookup function and am getting the "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed error."

My code is as follows:

```
Sub findprice()
    Dim partnumber As Variant
    Dim price As Integer
    Dim pricelist As Range
    Set pricelist = ActiveSheet.Range("a12:b21")
    partnumber = InputBox("enter part number")
    price = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partnumber, Range("pricelist"), 2)
    MsgBox price
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of `Range("pricelist")`  just use `pricelist` by itself no quotes. It is a range.

Comment: Also add `False` as a final argument to `VLookup()` if you need exact matches.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks